# Sci-fi novel that contains a drug that allow to re-live past episodes of your life

Tags: novel, psychology, story-identification

I am looking for the title of a SF novel (I think from the 70's or 80's) that includes a drug allowing its users to relive past events of their own lives. At some point there is a cult using this drug to "help" his members to do a kind of "deep" psychoanalysis by relieving traumatic events of their life. The catch is that this "re living" happens at the same speed as the original event.

One of the character (the wife of the main character I believe) is planning to re-live all of her life from the start to get kind of "clear", as she is about 30 this process will take her 30 years and she will be 60 at the end of her "analysis".

I just can not place this story, I would like to read it again, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I just found the answer. It was not a novel but a short story by Dan Simmons called "Flashback" in the book "Lovedeath". Simmons has recently published a full novel based on the same idea, called "Flashback," too.

Answer (score 4):

This reminds me of a book I almost bought but never got round to doing so. Its called "Confessions of a Memory Eater" - however its not as old as 70s/80s. The story is about a designer drug that is created that allows you to spend 2hrs reliving memories. The pill is called "Mem" and the story focuses on a guy named Win Duncan age 40, who is a sort of "beta-tester" of the pill. He does have a wife.. I dunno maybe I'm wrong, but it's worth checking out I think :)

Comment: Well, this is similar, in the cSe of the one i am looking for tghe reliving was kind of open ended. I do not remember how the peoples under the influence of the drug were supposed to eat through !

Comment: Im a bit useless about whether its 100% correct as i've not read it yet, but Im now gonna buy it because I'd forgotten all about it until I read this question :P

Comment: Thank you for the title of this book! "Confessions of a Memory Eater" has been haunting me for years - it's definitely worth checking out! I read it a few years back and couldn't get the story out of my head - but also couldn't (ironically) remember the title or author. Every now and then I would search with a few key words, and no results, but FINALLY I found this entry. The book was published in 2006 and the author is Pagan Kennedy. The pill "Mem" in the story was a super memory enhancer that brought on vivid hyper-real recall. While "under," the user would lose consciousness of their curren